# How do I include a break time in a countdown timer app for Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, countdowntimer

I'm building an Android app, which is similar to a pomodoro timer. Basically a user can set a work time and a break time and depending on how many sessions that user sets, the timer will initiate the work time, then break time, and then repeat until its reached the number of sessions the user has specified.

What I'm struggling with is how to approach creating a break time. When creating the break time, would it just restart the instance of `CountDownTimer` that I already have but set with the break time, or should I create a new instance of `CountDownTimer`? Should I create an array of `CountDownTimer` that would be something like `[work, break, work, break]` and then this would replace my single work time that I've created in `startTimer()`?

More importantly, I'm trying to figure out how to break down problems on my own, so how might I break down thinking about this problem?

Inside of `TimerFragment.kt`:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        ...

        // Setup button actions
        buttonTimerStartPause?.setOnClickListener {
            if (isTimerRunning) {
                pauseTimer()
            } else {
                startTimer()
            }
        }

private fun startTimer() {
        countDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(timeLeftInMillis,
                MILLIS_IN_ONE_SECOND.toLong() - 900) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                timeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished
                progressBarUpdate?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                progressBarStatic?.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                updateCountDownText()
                updateProgressBar()
        }

            override fun onFinish() {
                isTimerRunning = false
                updateButtonVisibility()
            }
        }.start()

        isTimerRunning = true
        updateButtonVisibility()
}
```

**Expected behaviour:**
If the user has set a 20 min work time and 5 min break time for 2 sessions, then the timer will run like this: 20min work, 5min break, 20min work, 5min break, and end.

What I have so far is an app where users can set a single work time, then start, pause or reset that work time. I've done this by using a `CountDownTimer`.

Comment: How did you program `pauseTimer()`?

Comment: @RahulKhurana by calling ```countDownTimer?.cancel()```

Comment: You can save the `millisUntilFinished` to save the current timer from  `onTick` method and then use the same milliSeconds to start the `CountDownTimer`

Comment: @RahulKhurana I'm not sure what you mean. For what purpose do we save the current timer from ```onTick()``` to ```millisUntilFinished```?


The work and break time will be set by the user

Comment: So basically you need to maintain a list of timer defined by the user and start the countdown on it. And after the timer is finished check if any other timer is pending to start.

Comment: @RahulKhurana That's one of the things I wasn't quite sure of is how could I create a list of timer? Would it be something like ```listOf(CountDownTimer(20), CountDownTimer(5), CountDownTimer(20), CountDownTimer(5))```? 

After creating a list of timer, how could I then control it to run one timer after another in the list?

Comment: yes, you're right. Inside `onFinish()` method check if the list is empty and if it isn't picked then use next entry and start time.

Answer (score 0):

No it will not create a new instance or not to restart the countdown timer, it just continue from where you stopped it or took a break.

[It Defines all methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zqSP.png)

[Methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXvbK.png)

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers my question. You've given implementations for the ```startTimer```, ```resetTimer``` and ```stopTimer``` which I've already defined.


What I'm trying to figure out is after the first ```countDownTimer``` ends, how should I define a second timer that will act as the break time. Then how should I call that second timer when the first one ends